# Are python methods chainable?

Tags: python, chainable

```
s = set([1,2,3])
```

I should be elegant to do the following:

```
a.update(s).update(s)
```

I doesn't work as I thought make a contains `set([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])`

So I'm wandering that Does Python advocate this chainable practise?

Comment: For a method to "chain," it has to return the object that it's acting on. As for whether it's a good practice or not, in general you should only chain methods that perform a clear, well-defined mutation on an object, and not something that potentially has complex side effects.

Comment: `set([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])` will return `set([1, 2, 3])` filtering the duplicate items, as set has unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

`set.update()` returns `None` so you can't chain updates like that

The usual rule in Python is that methods that mutate don't return the object

contrast with methods on immutable objects, which obviously must return a new object such as `str.replace()` which can be chained

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Methods that modify an object *usually* return `None` so you can't call a sequence of methods like this:

```
L.append(2).append(3).append(4)
```

And hope to have the same effect as:

```
L.append(2)
L.append(3)
L.append(4)
```

You'll probably get an `AttributeError` because the first call to `append` returns `None` and `None` does not have an `append` method.

Methods that creates new object returns that object, so for example:

```
"some string".replace("a", "b").replace("c", "d")
```

Is perfectly fine.

*Usually* immutable objects return new objects, while mutable ones return `None` but it depends on the method and the specific object.

Anyway it's certainly not a feature of the language itself but only a way to implement the methods. Chainable methods can be implemented in probably any language so the question "are python methods chainable" does not make much sense.
The only reasonable question would be "Are python methods always/forced to be/etc. chainable?", and the answer to this question is "No".

---

In your example `set` can only contain unique items, so the result that you show does not make any sense. You probably wanted to use a simple `list`.

Answer (score 0):

And `update` method does not return you a `set`, rather a `None` value.
So, you cannot invoke another method `update` in chain on `NoneType`

So, this will anyways give you error..

```
a.update(s).update(s)
```

However, since a `Set` can contain only `unique` values. So, even if you separate your `update` on different lines, you won't get a `Set` like you want..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can chain method calls in Python. As to whether it's good practice, there are a number of libraries out there which advocate using chained calls. For example, SQLAlchemy's [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html) makes extensive use of this style of coding. You frequently encounter code snippets like

```
session.query(User).filter(User.name.in_(['Edwardo', 'fakeuser'])).all()
```

A sensible guideline to adopt is to ask yourself whether it'll make the code easier to read and maintain. Always strive to make code readable.

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple example, chainable methods should always return an object ,like `self`,

```
class Chain(object):
    """Chain example"""
    def __init__(self):
        self._content = ''    
    def update(self, new_content):
        """method of appending content"""
        self._content += new_content
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        return self._content

>>> c = Chain()

>>> c.update('str1').update('str2').update('str3')

>>> print c
str1str2str3
```